# java.lang.NullPointerException when using eclipse

Tags: java

I am using gephi to implement a function as below, but I don't know where to put the "Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml" file so that eclipse can "see" it.

```
Container container;
try {
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml").toURI());
    container = importController.importFile(file);
    container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDefault.DIRECTED);   //Force DIRECTED
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can't mix File with Class#getResource, the resource may not be accessible via the file system

Comment: If you need a a File reference, you will need to out the file relative to the execution context of your application, I think in Eclipse, it's typically in the project directory

Comment: this code just actually correctly run in my classmates' computer, but why i cant use it? the only problem is i dont know where is the right place to place the "Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way it looks, the file should be places in the root of your source folders (another way to view it would be the default package). If you're using maven, put the file in the root of the `resources` folder.

Here's an example of the project structure:

```
your_project
- src
  + Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml
  - some.package.here
    + YourClass
```

Comment: oh, thank you!! the problem is solved as you said !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml").toURI());
```

And modify this:

```
container = importController.importFile(file);
```

To:

```
container = importController.importFile(getClass().getResource("Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml").toURI());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to understand the possible places where you can put your file, which is pretty complicated.

But, we can make it simpler, by putting your file in the location that you are familiar with, say C://Users/Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml. To do this, you need to modify:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml").toURI());
```

to

```
File file = new File("C://Users/Personal-May8-Anoymous.gml");
```

as simple as that.

Comment: Generally you don't want to do that. Your change will break JAR files, for one.

Comment: Well, that depends on how the code is deployed. I don't see the OP mentioned it has to work in general case. Let us see what the OP says.

Comment: I think it's preferable not to go from a more general solution that would work anywhere to one that is file system- and/or location-specific.

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is preferable to come up with the simplest solution that solves OP's problem. I don't understand why we use complex solution, but is actually not necessary. We can make the problem as complex as we want, right? For example, what if the GML file is in other machine? What if the JAR runs in OSGi environment, etc.

Comment: The simplest solution is to maintain the file inside the Jar. This solution looks simpler when you have control on the environment the application will be deployed but is risky if you or another user deletes the file or if you don't have any control on the environment to execute this application, which makes this solution complex.

Comment: Note: this code **won't work** on any OS different than Windows.

Comment: Relax. Let the OP picks which solution he prefers.